# jsPDF autotable 'Columns could not fit on page' when trying to print for small thermal pages

Tags: angular, typescript, printing, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am new to learning angular and jspdf.
I am facing an issue while using jspdf autotable to print for small pages (thermal page).
I tried many things but couldn't seem to work it out. The tabel is not fitting with the page.

This is my code:

```
onThermalPrint(){
let i = 1;
let products = [];
for (let invProduct of this.invoiceProducts) {
  let row = [];
  row.push(i++);
  row.push(invProduct.product.name);
  // row.push(invProduct.quantity);
  // row.push(invProduct.retailPrice);
  // row.push(invProduct.discount);
  row.push((invProduct.retailPrice - invProduct.discount) * invProduct.quantity);
  products.push(row);
}
let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', [80,57]);


let invoice_line_1;
let invoice_line_2;
for (let option of this.options) {
  if (option.name === 'invoice_line_1') invoice_line_1 = option.value;
  if (option.name === 'invoice_line_2') invoice_line_2 = option.value;
}

pdf.setFontSize(2);
pdf.text(invoice_line_1,1,2);
pdf.setFontSize(1);
pdf.text(invoice_line_2, 1, 2.5);

pdf.setFontSize(1);
pdf.text(`Salesperson    ${this.invoice.salesman.fullName}`, 15, 2);
pdf.setFontSize(1);

let address = "";
let customerName = `${this.invoice.customer.firstName} ${this.invoice.customer.lastName}`;
if (this.invoice.customer.streetAddress) address = `- ${this.invoice.customer.streetAddress}`;
pdf.text(`Customer              ${customerName} ${address}`, 1, 4);

pdf.text(`Invoice Date         ${new Date(this.invoice.invoiceDate).toUTCString()}`, 1, 5);

pdf.text(`Invoice Number    ${this.invoice.salesInvoiceNumber}`, 1, 6);

pdf.autoTable({
  startY: 7,
  tableWidth: 'auto', 
  columnWidth: 'wrap',
  tableLineWidth: 0,
  // pageBreak:'avoid',
  theme:'grid',
  bodyStyles:{
    halign: 'center'
  },
  styles: {
    fontSize: 1,
    overflow: 'linebreak',
    cellWidth: 'wrap'
  },
  columnStyles: {
    0: {cellWidth: 5},
    1: {cellWidth: 5},
    2: {cellWidth: 5},
  },
  head: [['Sr. #','Name','Amount']],
  body: products
});

let offset = pdf.previousAutoTable.finalY;
pdf.setFontSize(0.5);
pdf.text("All values are in PKR", 1, offset + 1);
pdf.setFontSize(1);

if (this.invoice.customer.shippingAddress) {
  pdf.text(`Billing Address         ${address}`, 1, offset + 2);
  pdf.text(`Shipping Address      ${this.invoice.customer.shippingAddress}`, 1, offset + 3);
}

pdf.text(`${this.invoice.invoiceTerms}`, 1, offset + 5);

pdf.text(`Total Tax           ${this.totalTax}`, 4, offset + 1);
pdf.text(`Shipping            ${this.invoice.shippingCharges}`, 4, offset + 2);
pdf.text(`Total Amount     ${this.totalAmount}`, 4, offset + 3);
pdf.text(`Grant Total        ${this.invoice.total}`, 4, offset + 4);

pdf.autoPrint({variant: 'non-conform'});
pdf.save(`thermalInvoice-${this.invoice.salesInvoiceNumber}.pdf`);}
```

These are the screenshots of the print.
[image: The First Page]

[image: This is the second page]

I am getting  'Columns could not fit on page' on my console.
How can I make the tables centered and fit to page.
I an using angular 7.'
Please help me with this issue as I am new to this.
Thank you.

Comment: You want it to fit the thermal page width or just align the table on middle? 
Also, i dont know if ( tableWidth: 'auto' ) will work properly if you define cellWidths.